# How to access the memory read/write access frequency corresponding to each pointer type argument in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am completely new to LLVM.

I am working on a pass to compute the load/store access frequency corresponding to each pointer argument to a function.

I am able to count the total number of load and store, however I wish to find the load/store corresponding to each pointer argument.

The code for counting the opcodes is same like : (slide 5)
http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ct/slides-16-17/llvm/4-lab3_intro.pdf